# How to group two value arrays to n value arrays in the below example?

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, grouping

I already have many two value arrays for example in the below

```
ary = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 3], [4, 5], [5, 6], [4, 7], [7, 8], [4, 8]]
```

I want to group them into

```
[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [5, 6], [4, 7, 8]
```

Because the meaning is 1 and 2 have relationship, 2 and 3 have relationship,1 and 3 have relationship,so 1,2,3 all have relationship

How can I do this by ruby lib or any algorithm?

Comment: Why is this being voted to be closed? It's pretty clear what's being asked.

Comment: Why the output should not be `[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8]`?

Comment: @Wand Maker Probably because last elements don't form clique (but author should claim this clearly)

Comment: @WandMaker Perhaps this might help: `[4,7,8]` is included because `[4,7]`, `[4,8]` and `[7,8]` exist.

Comment: I think OP is looking for a reversing of `combination`. Something like this backwards: `output = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[5,6],[4,7,8]]`,
`output.map {|a| a.combination(2).to_a}.flatten(1) #=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [4, 5], [5, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [7, 8]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a Ruby implementation of the basic [Bron–Kerbosch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm):

```
class Graph
  def initialize(edges)
    @edges = edges
  end

  def find_maximum_cliques
    @cliques ||= []
    bron_kerbosch([], nodes, []) if @cliques.empty?

    @cliques
  end

  private

  def nodes
    @nodes ||= @edges.flatten.uniq
  end

  def neighbours
    @neighbours ||= nodes.map do |node|
      node_neighbours =
        @edges.select { |edge| edge.include? node }.flatten - [node]

      [node, node_neighbours]
    end.to_h
  end

  def bron_kerbosch(re, pe, xe)
    @cliques << re if pe.empty? && xe.empty?

    pe.each do |ve|
      bron_kerbosch(re | [ve], pe & neighbours[ve], xe & neighbours[ve])
      pe -= [ve]
      xe |= [ve]
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
edges = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 3], [4, 5], [5, 6], [4, 7], [7, 8], [4, 8]]

Graph.new(edges).find_maximum_cliques # => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [4, 7, 8], [5, 6]]
```

There is a an optimization that can get it to `O(3^n/3)`.

Comment: Well done! You get my vote. Short and to the point. I now understand the difference between an array of all maximum cliques (your result), and a clique cover, in which `[4,5]` isn't present.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to shorten `find_maximum_cliques`, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

Your array can be seen as a Graph (e.g. Node 1 and Node 2 are connected by an Edge, as well as Node 2 and 3, ...)

You're looking for an Array of all the [maximum cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem). A [clique cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover) is an array of maximum cliques which contains every Node exactly once. This problem is [hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness).

A clique is a subset of your graph in which every node is connected to each other. If a node isn't connected to any other, it forms a clique with just one node, itself. A maximum clique is a clique which cannot be enlarged by adding another node.

This [gem](https://github.com/Ilink/Cliques) might be able to help you, with the `all_max_cliques` method. Here's a script you could write at the root of the Clique project :

```
require_relative 'src/graph.rb'
require_relative 'src/bron.rb'
require_relative 'src/max_clique.rb'
require_relative 'src/util.rb'
require 'set'

ary = [[1,2],[2,3],[1,3],[4,5],[5,6],[4,7],[7,8],[4,8]]

graph = Graph.new
graph = ary.each_with_object(Graph.new){|(n1,n2),graph| graph.insert(n1, [n2])}

all_max_cliques(graph.graph)
```

It outputs :

```
intersections after sort!: {3=>[2], 2=>[3]}
cliqueeee[3, 2, 1]
intersections after sort!: {3=>[1], 1=>[3]}
...
...
cliqueeee[6, 5]
intersections after sort!: {5=>[]}
cliqueeee[5, 6]
largest clique!: [6, 5]
[[3, 2, 1], [8, 7, 4], [6, 5]]
```

Note that if you want a clique cover, (i.e. a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set)), every node should appear exactly once. 5 and 6 form a maximum clique, and 4 is already inside `[4,7,8]`, so there's no need for `[4,5]`.

Here's a very basic bruteforce solution. Don't use it for anything big!

```
require 'set'

class Graph
  attr_reader :nodes, :edges

  def initialize(edges)
    @nodes = edges.flatten.sort.uniq
    @edges = edges.map(&:sort).to_set
  end

  def minimum_clique_cover
    partitions.select{ |p| all_cliques?(p) }.min_by(&:size)
  end

  private

  def partitions(array = nodes)
    if array.length == 1
      [[array]]
    else
      *head, tail = array
      partitions(head).inject([]) do |result, partition|
        result + (0..partition.length).collect do |index_to_add_at|
          new_partition = partition.dup
          new_partition[index_to_add_at] = (new_partition[index_to_add_at] || []) + [tail]
          new_partition
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def all_cliques?(partition)
    partition.all?{ |subset| clique?(subset) }
  end

  def clique?(subset)
    subset.permutation(2).select{ |n1, n2| n2 > n1 }.all?{ |edge| edges.include?(edge) }
  end
end

p Graph.new([[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 3], [4, 5], [5, 6], [4, 7], [7, 8], [4, 8]]).minimum_clique_cover
# => [[4, 7, 8], [5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

It returns a minimum clique cover, which is harder than just an Array of maximum cliques. Don't ask me about the complexity of this script, and I won't have to lie.

Comment: This is great, although I'd love to see some code working on the OP's example.